# Content staging extremely slow

Tags: kentico

Recently, content staging became extremely slow for our Kentico 8.2 application (to move a page, it's taking 30 minutes or more). Similar staging tasks before took seconds to complete. We have restarted the website, and that had no effect.

Before, we just had the one website in the Kentico instance. We recently deployed another website to the same instance. This could be a coincidence, but it is the only thing we can think of that might be affecting the staging performance. However, we do not understand why. Why would adding a second website slow down the content staging of a different website? How do we fix it? Also, if the addition of another website is just a coincidence, what are other things to check in the event of slow content staging? We don't really know where to start with this one.

**EDIT**
Sites are hosted on premise (not Azure) on same server.

Comment: Any errors in the eventlog?

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more about your environment and the new site you deployed.  Was there any custom code?  Does the old site have custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the table index fragmentation. It grows over a period of time and make the staging application slow.

Another thing to check, make a frequent sync of tasks / changes to higher environment to reduce the number of records to keep a track.

Hope this helps in resolving your issue.

Comment: Excessive logic on Global Event hooks can also cause an issue, so they should check if they are using Global Event hooks to perform logic on Document insert/updates, etc.

Comment: It appears that we had some users creating staging tasks for a while without moving them to the higher environments, for an extended period of time (for business reasons). I don't know for sure, but I think the volume of changes had something to do with the performance issue.

Comment: Our staging is going faster now. We ended up clearing the staging task queue entirely, and synching individual subtrees one by one. Still having a few issues, but definitely going faster now. I'll mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: happy to help solving your issue.